# JIRA What is the process for moving incomplete tickets to new project/sprint

Tags: jira, agile

We are starting a whole new project this upcoming sprint, but some tickets from last sprint were not completed.

What is the process on JIRA to handle this? How do I transfer tickets to the next sprint if it's a different project altogether? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To move issues/stories to another project:

1. Create a new Project
2. In the old project, select the issues to move. Then use the context menu and select multi-change. There you can select "move issues" where you will be asked to name the new project.
3. Done.

If you want copies to remain in your old project you have to clone the issues first.